# Получить значения родительского элемента при клике по дочернему

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    #HTML
  <tr class="odd">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    </tr>
```

Необходимо при клике по ячейке в таблице подняться вверх по DOM модели и найти первый встреченный  элемент и получить из него всю информацию, т.е. содержимое дочерних полей . 
Попытался сделать следующим образом, но возвращает Object object, либо undefined, если указываю индекс

```
(this).onclick = function(){
var a = $(this).parent().find("tr").val()
alert(a)}
```

Как можно реализовать идею?

Comment: `найти первый встреченный элемент и получить из него всю информацию` - всмысле взять содержимое текущей строки? или соседнего `td`? И кто такой `(this).onclick` ?

Comment: Нужно получить содержимое всех <td>, т.е. содержимое текущей строки. (this).onclick - событие клика, с точки зрения синтаксиса проблем нет

Comment: Проблема с точки зрения здравого смысла. `(this).onclick` задает единсвенный обработчик клика для этого элемента. Если на эти элементы были повешены другие обработчики  - они вызываться не будут.

Comment: В данном контексте лучше `$(this).click(...)` или `$(this).on('click', ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, можно так:

```js
$('td').on('click', function(e){
  var parent = $(e.currentTarget).parent();
  if(parent){
    //ищите, что вам нужно
    var results = parent.find('td');
    console.log('значение 1-й ячейки: ' + $(results[0]).html());
    console.log('значение последней ячейки: ' + $(results[results.length - 1]).html());
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr class="odd">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even">
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Найти ближайшего предка по селектору

```
var row = $(this).closest("tr");
```

Потом уже выбирать селекторами из `$(__селектор__, row)...`